# Not Able to Insert Data into Database String or binary data would be truncated

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, insert

```
 INSERT INTO [CVSUAT].[dbo].[UserLevel ]( 
  [Client_ID]
  ,[User_Level_Name]
  ,[User_Level_Description]
  ,[Created_by]
  ,[Created_Date]
  ,[Modified_by]
  ,[Modified_Date]
  ,[Delete_Flag]
  ,[Deactivate_Flag]) VALUES ('sndbsndbsdnbsndbsnbdnsbdn23','Client','','Client','2013-03-12 21:31:38.437','Client','2013-03-12 21:31:38.437','0','0')
```

**Msg 8152, Level 16, State 4, Line 1
String or binary data would be truncated.
The statement has been terminated.**

[image]

**NOTE:** My Table has a space [UserLevel ] as it was made that way from before

Comment: get rid of that fricking trailing space! That's ridiculous. Talk about technical debt!

Comment: Is `User_Level_ID` an identity column? Also just a side note, `Delete-Flag` and `Deactivate_Flag` sounds like they should be `BIT` columns.

Comment: As all of your columns are nullable (except the PK), why are you entering empty string into some of them for unknown values? You could have just not inserted into them at all, and left them as null.

Comment: What's the bet, that that trailing space is still there in 5 years time...

Comment: @MitchWheat You're assuming the company lasts that long ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by attempting to put too much data into a column.

The trouble is, none of the values specified in your example are too large for the columns indicated in your schema picture. I'd therefore assume that the values you've given us either aren't the true values, or you've got a trigger on that table, which is actually what is causing the error.

As an aside, shouldn't your `Delete_Flag` and `Deactivate_Flag` columns be of datatype bit, rather than `char(1)`?

**Edit:**

Oh, and one more thing - as `Client_ID` is an nvarchar, you probably want to store unicode data in there. To indicate this in your script, you should use the "N" prefix on your strings, like so:

```
INSERT INTO [CVSUAT].[dbo].[UserLevel ]( 
  [Client_ID]
  ,[User_Level_Name]
  ,[User_Level_Description]
  ,[Created_by]
  ,[Created_Date]
  ,[Modified_by]
  ,[Modified_Date]
  ,[Delete_Flag]
  ,[Deactivate_Flag]) VALUES (N'sndbsndbsdnbsndbsnbdnsbdn23','Client','','Client','2013-03-12 21:31:38.437','Client','2013-03-12 21:31:38.437','0','0')
```